# Query to select value from another table as a column

Tags: mysql

I have a query to report some data :

```
select r.m_id, 
count(distinct case when r.sal = '1val' then r.login end) as 1val,
count(distinct case when r.sal = '2val' then r.login end) as 2val,
count(distinct case when r.sal = '3val' then r.login end) as 3val,
...
from read_log r
inner join mes m on m.id = r.m_id

where 
YEAR(m.send_date) = YEAR(curdate()) 
group by r.m_id
```

`r.sal` value in `count(distinct case when r.sal = '1val' then r.login end) as 1val` only changes. Finally it shows results in each column for every `r.sal`. There are currently over 80 diffrent `r.sal` and its growing.

My question is:
It is possible to take value for `r.sal` from another table?
Like new table `sal` with this `1val`, `2val`, `3val`, `4val`, `5val` etc...?
Maybe loop or something like that:
`count(distinct case when r.sal = (select val from sal) then r.login end)`
(I know its wrong but maybe it will illustrate it better)

`count(distinct case...` is great to show data for each `r.sal` value in the other column but maybe is another way to achieve that...

Comment: *It is possible to take value for r.sal from another table?* Of course. But in this case you'd have one aggregate value for one definite `sal` value per row, and hence you'd pivot this rowset. So I think that stored procedure with dynamic SQL (based on `sal` values table) is more suitable solution.

Comment: @Akina Any chance to show it to me? I have no experience with procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE sal_table (sal CHAR(4));
INSERT INTO sal_table VALUES ('1val'), ('2val'), ... ;
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_data ()
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT ( 
        'select r.m_id, ',
        GROUP_CONCAT( 
            CONCAT( 
                'count(distinct case when r.sal = ''',
                sal,
                ''' then r.login end) as `',
                sal,
                '`'
                )
            ),
        ' from read_log r ',
        'inner join mes m on m.id = r.m_id ',
        'where YEAR(m.send_date) = YEAR(curdate()) ',
        'group by r.m_id' 
        )
    INTO @sql
    FROM sal_table;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af55c52aca3280410fba1f3a453aab09

PS. Recommended edition: `WHERE m.send_date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-01-01') AND m.send_date < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y-01-01')`. Such condition is sargable rather than your one.

Comment: thank You. however I have error when I try to run it with `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read_log r inner join mes m on m.id = r.m_id where YEAR(m.send_date) ' at line 1`. MySQL version: Distrib 5.6.50

Comment: @fosfik This code works on 5.6: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=af55c52aca3280410fba1f3a453aab09 and even on 5.5 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=af55c52aca3280410fba1f3a453aab09 You did something wrongly - be more accurate. Do like is made on the fiddle - obtain the built query text then try to execute it.

Comment: CONCAT may have a character limit? In 13 case it looks like this: `count(distinct case when r.sal = 'S06W' th from read_log r inner join`?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT have max length 1024. I added after `BEGIN` : `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;`. It works great now. Thanks Akina!